# Certificate error for Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

Over the past couple of days, I have been trying to access Gmail in Chrome by navigating to https://gmail.com. As seen in the error below, it says the server identifies itself as mail.google.com not gmail.com. Makes sense, right? I can type mail.google.com into Chrome and use Gmail webapp just fine but typing gmail.com returns the error attached. Gmail.com and mail.google.com work without problems in Safari. My certificates in Keychain Access seem ok but I do not know much about how they work.

[image]

I have tried clearing Chrome's browsing data

Technical details:

- OS X 10.8.4
- Google Chrome 28.0.1500.95
- Safari 6.0.5

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Ok I just submitted this to the Google through the Report an issue option in Chrome. If I hear anything, I will update here.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what was preventing me from accessing Gmail via `gmail.com`. avast! antivirus had "Scan secure connections" enabled in the web shield. I disabled that option, which I forgot I had manually enabled earlier this summer. Other antivirus applications like Kaspersky have a similar function that could be doing the same thing. The "Scan secure connections" was also blocking Apple Software Updates via the Mac App Store.